# Print data retrieved in JSON on a PHP

Tags: php, html, json, api, rest

I'm trying to print a table with the list of Monitoring Groups from data retrieved from a REST API. The results come back in JSON. Below is the JSON data:

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "success",
    "data":
    [
        {
            "group_id": "169839000000116001",
            "display_name": "MTI Servers",
            "description": "",
            "monitors":
            [
            ]
        },
        {
            "group_id": "169839000000180001",
            "display_name": "PRB Servers",
            "description": "",
            "monitors":
            [
                "169839000000179003",
                "169839000000176013",
                "169839000000175003",
                "169839000000176007"
            ]
        },
        {
            "group_id": "169839000000046270",
            "display_name": "DB Servers",
            "description": "",
            "monitors":
            [
                "169839000000051011",
                "169839000000047023",
                "169839000000078001"
            ]
        },
        {
            "group_id": "169839000000025200",
            "display_name": "EXT Apps",
            "description": "External Monitoring of Applications",
            "monitors":
            [
                "169839000000025274",
                "169839000000025377",
                "169839000000025359",
                "169839000000025369",
                "169839000000025385",
                "169839000000025226"
            ]
        },
        {
            "group_id": "169839000000025109",
            "display_name": "EXT Services",
            "description": "External monitoring of services.",
            "monitors":
            [
                "169839000000046165",
                "169839000000025256",
                "169839000000025168",
                "169839000000025202",
                "169839000000025189",
                "169839000000025217",
                "169839000000025265"
            ]
        },
        {
            "group_id": "169839000000046015",
            "display_name": "ZMB Servers",
            "description": "",
            "monitors":
            [
                "169839000000050017",
                "169839000000050025",
                "169839000000049001",
                "169839000000050001",
                "169839000000053019",
                "169839000000051003",
                "169839000000050009"
            ]
        },
        {
            "group_id": "169839000000046282",
            "display_name": "NWK Devices",
            "description": "",
            "monitors":
            [
                "169839000000082009",
                "169839000000084077",
                "169839000000084001",
                "169839000000082229"
            ]
        },
        {
            "group_id": "169839000000046013",
            "display_name": "VBR Servers",
            "description": "",
            "monitors":
            [
                "169839000000047007"
            ]
        },
        {
            "group_id": "169839000000054197",
            "display_name": "LNX Servers",
            "description": "",
            "monitors":
            [
                "169839000000060483"
            ]
        },
        {
            "group_id": "169839000000046020",
            "display_name": "VSP Servers",
            "description": "",
            "monitors":
            [
                "169839000000060177",
                "169839000000060170",
                "169839000000060088",
                "169839000000060095",
                "169839000000060102",
                "169839000000060109",
                "169839000000054102"
            ]
        },
        {
            "group_id": "169839000000046058",
            "display_name": "WND Servers",
            "description": "",
            "monitors":
            [
                "169839000000066001",
                "169839000000063119"
            ]
        },
        {
            "group_id": "169839000000128001",
            "display_name": "TPT Servers",
            "description": "",
            "monitors":
            [
                "169839000000143041",
                "169839000000148017",
                "169839000000127035",
                "169839000000123003",
                "169839000000126011",
                "169839000000122011",
                "169839000000129001",
                "169839000000158028"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to print the Group ID, Name, Description and the list of monitor IDs that belong to the group.  I'm using json_decode but I cant seem to read the correct variables from the array.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
`<?php
/**
 * Connect to the Site API and extract the list of monitor groups
 */

 // URL to fetch
  $url = "https://www.mymonitorsite.com/api/monitor_groups";

 // Initialize cURL session
  $ch = curl_init($url);

 // Option to Return the Result, rather than just true/false
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 // Set Custom Headers
 $headers = array(
        'Authorization: Authtoken 12345678901234567890123456789012',
        'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept: application/json; version=2.0',
 );

 // Option to set the custom headers
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

 // Perform the request, and save content to $result
  $mongrps_json = curl_exec($ch);

 // Close the cURL resource, and free up system resources!
  curl_close($ch);

 // Decode json data into a PHP Array
  $mongrps_array = json_decode($mongrps_json, true);   
?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <title>Monitor Group Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php
      // List the first monitor group here (test)
      echo "Group ID   = " . $mongrps_array->data[0]->group_id . "<br>";
      echo "Group Name = " . $mongrps_array->data[0]->display_name . <br>";
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
`
```

Here's a var_dump of the json_decode:

```
array(3) { ["code"]=> int(0) ["message"]=> string(7) "success" ["data"]=> array(12) { [0]=> array(4) { ["group_id"]=> string(18) "169839000000116001" ["display_name"]=> string(11) "MTI Servers" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["monitors"]=> array(0) { } } [1]=> array(4) { ["group_id"]=> string(18) "169839000000180001" ["display_name"]=> string(11) "PRB Servers" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["monitors"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(18) "169839000000179003" [1]=> string(18) "169839000000176013" [2]=> string(18) "169839000000175003" [3]=> string(18) "169839000000176007" } } [2]=> array(4) { ["group_id"]=> string(18) "169839000000046270" ["display_name"]=> string(10) "DB Servers" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["monitors"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(18) "169839000000051011" [1]=> string(18) "169839000000047023" [2]=> string(18) "169839000000078001" } } [3]=> array(4) { ["group_id"]=> string(18) "169839000000025200" ["display_name"]=> string(8) "EXT Apps" ["description"]=> string(35) "External Monitoring of Applications" ["monitors"]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(18) "169839000000025274" [1]=> string(18) "169839000000025377" [2]=> string(18) "169839000000025359" [3]=> string(18) "169839000000025369" [4]=> string(18) "169839000000025385" [5]=> string(18) "169839000000025226" } } [4]=> array(4) { ["group_id"]=> string(18) "169839000000025109" ["display_name"]=> string(12) "EXT Services" ["description"]=> string(31) "External monitoring of services" ["monitors"]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(18) "169839000000046165" [1]=> string(18) "169839000000025256" [2]=> string(18) "169839000000025168" [3]=> string(18) "169839000000025202" [4]=> string(18) "169839000000025189" [5]=> string(18) "169839000000025217" [6]=> string(18) "169839000000025265" } } [5]=> array(4) { ["group_id"]=> string(18) "169839000000046015" ["display_name"]=> string(11) "ZMB Servers" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["monitors"]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(18) "169839000000050017" [1]=> string(18) "169839000000050025" [2]=> string(18) "169839000000049001" [3]=> string(18) "169839000000050001" [4]=> string(18) "169839000000053019" [5]=> string(18) "169839000000051003" [6]=> string(18) "169839000000050009" } } [6]=> array(4) { ["group_id"]=> string(18) "169839000000046282" ["display_name"]=> string(11) "NWK Devices" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["monitors"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(18) "169839000000082009" [1]=> string(18) "169839000000084077" [2]=> string(18) "169839000000084001" [3]=> string(18) "169839000000082229" } } [7]=> array(4) { ["group_id"]=> string(18) "169839000000046013" ["display_name"]=> string(11) "VBR Servers" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["monitors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(18) "169839000000047007" } } [8]=> array(4) { ["group_id"]=> string(18) "169839000000054197" ["display_name"]=> string(11) "LNX Servers" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["monitors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(18) "169839000000060483" } } [9]=> array(4) { ["group_id"]=> string(18) "169839000000046020" ["display_name"]=> string(11) "VSP Servers" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["monitors"]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(18) "169839000000060177" [1]=> string(18) "169839000000060170" [2]=> string(18) "169839000000060088" [3]=> string(18) "169839000000060095" [4]=> string(18) "169839000000060102" [5]=> string(18) "169839000000060109" [6]=> string(18) "169839000000054102" } } [10]=> array(4) { ["group_id"]=> string(18) "169839000000046058" ["display_name"]=> string(11) "WND Servers" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["monitors"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "169839000000066001" [1]=> string(18) "169839000000063119" } } [11]=> array(4) { ["group_id"]=> string(18) "169839000000128001" ["display_name"]=> string(11) "TPT Servers" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["monitors"]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(18) "169839000000143041" [1]=> string(18) "169839000000148017" [2]=> string(18) "169839000000127035" [3]=> string(18) "169839000000123003" [4]=> string(18) "169839000000126011" [5]=> string(18) "169839000000122011" [6]=> string(18) "169839000000129001" [7]=> string(18) "169839000000158028" } } } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `foreach` loop to display the following data:

- group_id
- display_name
- description and
- monitors(as a comma separated list)

  ```
  $mongrps_array = json_decode($mongrps_json, true);

  foreach($mongrps_array['data'] as $arr){
      foreach($arr as $key => $value){
          if($key == "monitors"){
              echo $key . ": " . implode(", ", $value) . "<br />";
          }else{
              echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
          }
      }
      echo "<br />";
  }
  ```

Comment: @DennisAyala Glad I could help. Please mark the answer as *accepted* if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: @DennisAyala You can't upvote an answer, but you can certainly *accept* answers by clicking the green tick icon on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I Just tried, should not be any issue to get the data you are looking for.

For example, to get the group_id of the first item in the array:

```
echo $decodedJson->data[0]->group_id;
```

Maybe you are trying to get the data as arrays? In this case, pass the parameter `true` to the `json_decode` function:

```
$decodedJson = json_decode($originalJson, true);
echo $decodedJson['data'][0]['group_id'];
```

Comment: I used the `true` parameter with the `json_decode` function. I tried your example but it didn't display anything at all.

Comment: Try to `var_dump` the value you get from `json_decode`, if it's null, it means that it failed to decode the json for some reason.